# Get a bulk pipeline runs providing run ids as a list from .NET

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have an endpoint which tells me the `status` of a given adf pipeline from .NET. For that purpose I use the .NET sdk for ADF, specifically I run `PipelineRun pipelineRun = client.PipelineRuns.Get(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, runId);` and then I retrieve the status from `pipelineRun.Status`. The only thing I get from an user here is `runId`. However, I have a scenario where I need to send a list of `runIds`. From what I've seen, reading the official documentation, I noticed that most of their apis work with `runId` of type `str` which means it works only per `runId`? Has any of you ever stumbled upon a scenario like this and how did you manage to get `status` of multiple `runIds`? Did you use an already built function from the SDK or you just `for-looped` the `PipelineRun pipelineRun = client.PipelineRuns.Get(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, runId);` for `listSize` times?

Comment: Please refer [GET ANY AZURE DATA FACTORY PIPELINE RUN STATUS WITH AZURE FUNCTIONS](https://mrpaulandrew.com/2019/11/21/get-any-azure-data-factory-pipeline-run-status-with-azure-functions/)

Comment: I couldn't find an example which gets a list of ids as an input param. As far as I could see, filtering done here is by a PipelineName and a date range @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT